# How to publish Edge extensions on the Windows Store?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Since the Windows 10 Anniversary Update I started developing extensions for Edge.

I'd like to publish some of them on the Windows Store however I don't know how. I'm currently sideloading the extension. How do you package it and submit it?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/extensions-for-enterprise/

Comment: I have found that too. "Instructions on packaging extensions are available through the Technology Adoption Program (TAP)." - does that mean it's not yet possible? because TAP is about pre-release MS products

Comment: Somewhere I have read that you can publish it but you have to be lucky and stand out... They will test your extension first and finally they will allow you to publish it. I believe that they need to be extra sure about app quality and security. You will also need Windows Store developer account.

Comment: I do have a developer account but I don't know how to package the extension and how to submit so they can do that quality control thing

Comment: More info here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/faq/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Updated (2017-07-11):

Microsoft rolled out the next stage: It is now possible to [submit an extension for review](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/requests/).

### Updated (2016-12-19):

Microsoft Edge has published the [packaging documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/guides/packaging/), and also mentioned the following:

> Submitting a Microsoft Edge extension to the Windows Store is currently a restricted capability. [Reach out to us](http://aka.ms/extension-request) with your requests to be a part of the Windows Store, and we’ll consider you for a future update.

### Updated (2016-11-21):

According to [Building, Testing and Deploying a Browser Extension in Microsoft Edge](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/New-Zealand-2016/M357), which is a session in [Microsoft Ignite NZ](https://msignite.nz/), if you're interested in deploying your extensions to the Windows Store, please consider submitting a request to https://aka.ms/extension-request to be considered for a future update.

### Previous:

Microsoft Edge is not accepting public submissions to the store at this time (Updated on 2016-11-21). See the [response from Kyle Pflug](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/08/04/introducing-edgehtml-14/) (Program Magager of Microsoft Edge):
[image]

And from offical FAQ, Microsoft Edge also states that they are [intentionally starting with a small set of extensions and the list of extensions is locked, for the reason of reliability, performance and functionality.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/faq/)

[image]