# How to pack the edge browser extension for publish to store

Tags: browser, packaging, microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I have developed the extension for microsoft edge browser.Now i want to pack the extension so that i can publish it. But I have not found any information that how to pack the extension. Can anyone tell me how to pack it.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish Edge extensions on the Windows Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803483/how-to-publish-edge-extensions-on-the-windows-store)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't.

> For the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, we are intentionally starting with a small set of extensions. The list of extensions is locked - you can see the list [at our extensions page here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/). We want to be mindful about what extensions are available on the platform and watch for telemetry and feedback and make sure the reliability, performance and functionality of the browser isn’t impacted by these new features. Extension developers can submit a request to https://aka.ms/extension-request to be considered for a future update.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/faq/

Answer (score 1):

Newly released steps for packaging an Edge extension are available here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/guides/packaging/

As Elad mentions, however, submitting to the Windows Store is still a process managed by Microsoft. Submitting a request to https://aka.ms/extension-request will get you added to the list for future consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Visual Studio 2015 Community to do it (free download from Microsoft).  I've been trying the same thing, but I'm using Windows 7 and it keeps crashing, so I don't know if it's possible from my OS (or even if publishing an "app" is the same as publishing an "extension").

[Packaging Apps for Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454036.aspx)