# Publish an Edge extension to store

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I see this question on stackoverflow, but that seem it is very old (one year ago [How to publish Edge extensions on the Windows Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803483/how-to-publish-edge-extensions-on-the-windows-store)). I tried, but I just got error:

> Sorry, your account type is not supported AAD (Azure Active Directory)
>   accounts are not supported at this time. You need to use a regular
>   Microsoft account like the one you can create here.

How can I publish an Edge extension to store? Is it still free or need to pay?

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you are trying to publish an Extension using a work account. I think you need to create a Microsoft Developer account now (Not free) to publish an Extension to Store

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).